# Accessing each ng-template name using @ContentChildren()

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular6, ng-template

I have written a component named `my-component` and added some `ng-template` inside, and named each with `#` like this:

```
<my-component>
    <ng-template #one>
        1st format
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template  #two>
        2nd template
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template  #three>
        3rd template
    </ng-template>
</my-component>
```

at the declaration of `MyComponent`, I used `@ContentChildren(TemplateRef)` to access these three templates.

Now I need to access the names of these templates (`one`, `two`, `three`) somehow inside `MyComponent` but I don't know how.
Here is the code: [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/gLum5z0b/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0pd4g5va/

Comment: You can simply use `ngAfterContentInit` hook to get all the templates

Comment: @yurzui can you please explain? also if possible explain with help of ngAfterContentInit as well

Comment: @yurzui you are my hero :)

Comment: It works well, but the result children aren't `TemplateRef` anymore, and can't deal them as `TemplateRef`  @yurzui

Comment: When I try to cast it into `TemplateRef` or use it as a `TemplateRef` I get this error:
`Property 'elementRef' is missing in type 'NamedTemplate'.`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tvm9gjuc/

Comment: A dirty solution: `(template as any)._declarationTContainer.localNames[0]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a component which uses **ng-templates** and I struggled to find documentation about it. A bit of trial and error and I figured out how to use the **@ContentChild**

```
  @ContentChild('one') oneTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('two') twoTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

and then in the UI **html template of my-component** you use them like this:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="oneTemplate"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="twoTemplate"></ng-container>
```

The **component usage** would be like you described:

```
<my-component>
    <ng-template #one>
        1st format
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template  #two>
        2nd template
    </ng-template>
</my-component>
```

Hope this helps and works for someone. Feedback appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to do with and pass down context that has proper type-completion?

Comment: @TroyWeber still not possible 